# How can I preserve an inner symbol when assigning a new value to an html field?

Tags: javascript, html

We have a field that is a dropdown and will display the user's alias. To emphasize it's a dropdown there's a class called `caret` that displays a triangle.

The code for this part is written in html like this.

```
<a
  id="username"
  href="#"
  class="dropdown-toggle"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  role="button"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false"
>**username will go here**<i id="caret" class="caret"></i>
</a>
```

The caret disappears when we assign a value to "username". I think it's because `<i id="caret" class="caret"></i>` is within that class.

So what I thought about doing to remedy this is add the class to string at the time of reassignment like so

```
$('#username').text(name);
$('#username').addClass("caret")
```

Clearly this is not the right approach, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question. How can I keep the triangle from disappearing when the field is populated?

I also moved the class outside of `id=username` which messed up how the page displays.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a
  href="#"
  class="dropdown-toggle"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  role="button"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false"
><span id="username">**username will go here**</span><i id="caret" class="caret"></i>
</a> 


$('#username').text(name);
```